# Alter number string in pandas column

Tags: python, string, pandas, text, apply

**Background**

I have a sample `df` with a `Text` column containing 0,1, or >1 `ABC`'s

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Jon J Mmith  ABC: 1111111 is this here', 
                                   'ABC: 1234567 Mary Lisa Rider found here', 
                                   'Jane A Doe is also here',
                                'ABC: 2222222 Tom T Tucker is here ABC: 2222222 too'], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3,4],
                      'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

                     })

#rearrange columns
df = df[['Text','N_ID', 'P_ID']]
df

                            Text                      N_ID  P_ID
0   Jon J Mmith ABC: 1111111 is this here               A1  1
1   ABC: 1234567 Mary Lisa Rider found here             A2  2
2   Jane A Doe is also here                             A3  3
3   ABC: 2222222 Tom T Tucker is here ABC: 2222222...   A4  4
```

**Goal**

1) Change the `ABC` numbers in `Text` column (e.g `ABC: 1111111`) to `ABC: **BLOCK**`

2) Create a new column `Text_ABC` containing this output

**Desired Output**

```
                             Text                  N_ID P_ID Text_ABC
0   Jon J Mmith ABC: 1111111 is this here          A1   1   Jon J Mmith ABC: **BLOCK** is this here
1   ABC: 1234567 Mary Lisa Rider found here        A2   2   ABC: **BLOCK** Mary Lisa Hider found here   
2   Jane A Doe is also here                        A3   3   Jane A Doe is also here 
3   ABC: 2222222 Tom T Tucker is here ABC: 2222222 A4   4   ABC: **BLOCK** Tom T Tucker is here ABC: **BLOCK**
```

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your numerics are to be replaced, you can do:

```
df['Text_ABC'] = df['Text'].replace(r'\d+', '***BLOCK***', regex=True)
```

But if you want to be more specific and only replace the numerics after `ABC:`, then you can use this:

```
df['Text_ABC'] = df['Text'].replace(r'ABC: \d+', 'ABC: ***BLOCK***', regex=True)
```

Giving you:

```
df
                                                Text  P_ID N_ID                                           Text_ABC
0             Jon J Smith  ABC: 1111111 is this here     1   A1           Jon J Smith  ABC: ***BLOCK*** is this here
1            ABC: 1234567 Mary Lisa Rider found here     2   A2          ABC: ***BLOCK*** Mary Lisa Rider found here
2                            Jane A Doe is also here     3   A3                            Jane A Doe is also here
3  ABC: 2222222 Tom T Tucker is here ABC: 2222222...     4   A4  ABC: ***BLOCK*** Tom T Tucker is here ABC: ***BLOCK...
```

As a regex, `\d+` means "match one or more consecutive digits", so using that within [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) says to "replace one or more consecutive digits with `***BLOCK***`"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of `\d+`. Question: what would the analogous regex expression to `\d+` be if  we were trying to replace an `MRN` string that is "followed by one or more consecutive characters (not digits)" e.g. `MRN: Jon J Smith`

Comment: `MRN.*` would match `MRN` and all following characters I think

Comment: I tried but it didn't quit work. I will just ask another SO question. Thanks anyway!