# modification of alter number string pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, replace

**Background**

I have the following sample `df` which is an alternation of [Alter number string in pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031837/alter-number-string-in-pandas-column)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Jon J Smith  Record #:  0000004 is this ', 
                                   'Record #:  0000003 Mary Lisa Hider found here', 
                                   'Jane A Doe is also here Record #:  0000002',
                                'Record #:  0000001'], 

                      'P_ID': [1,2,3,4],
                      'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

                     })

#rearrange columns
df = df[['Text','N_ID', 'P_ID']]
df

                                    Text             N_ID   P_ID
0   Jon J Smith Record #: 0000004 is this       A1  1
1   Record #: 0000003 Mary Lisa Hider fou...    A2  2
2   Jane A Doe is also here Record #: 000...    A3  3
3   Record #: 0000001                           A4  4
```

**Goal**

1) replace number after `Record #:` with `**BLOCK**`

`Jon J Smith  Record #:  0000004 is this`
`Jon J Smith  Record #:  **BLOCK** is this`

2) create new column

**Desired Output**

```
    Text    N_ID    P_ID    New_Text              
0                          Jon J Smith Record #: **BLOCK** is this      
1                          Record #: **BLOCK**  Mary Lisa Hider fou...  
2                          Jane A Doe is also here Record #: **BLOCK**  
3                          Record #: **BLOCK**
```

**Tried**

I have tried the following but this is not quite right

```
df['New_Text']= df['Text'].replace(r'(?i)record\s+#: \d+', r"Date of Birth: **BLOCK**", regex=True)
```

**Question**

How do I alter my code to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching a single space after the `:` which you could turn into `\s+` (or repeat a space  `+` if it can only be spaces) and use a capturing group for the first part.

```
(?i)(medical\s+record\s+#:\s+)\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H1h4XY/1)

In the replacement use

```
\1**BLOCK**
```

The final piece of code will look like this

```
df['New_Text']= df['Text'].replace(r'(?i)(medical\s+record\s+#:\s+)\d+', r"\1**BLOCK**", regex=True)
```